# Can I prove Hölder's inequality given duality of $p$- and $q$-norms?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

The only fact I know is
$$||x||_p=\max_{||z||_q\le1}|z^Tx|$$
Of course, $\frac1p+\frac1q=1$.

Based on the definition of $||x||_p$, I want to prove Hölder's inequality that for all $x,y$:
$$|x^Ty|\le||x||_p||y||_q$$

I know how to prove Hölder's inequality based on Young's inequality and the definition of $p$-norms, but do I need those low-level proofs here?

Comment: It just follows from the definition, since ${1 \over \|z\|_q} z^T x \le \|x\|_p$.

Comment: @copper.hat Could you explain why that holds?

Comment: It follows from the definition of $\|\cdot \|_p$ which is the $\max$ of $z^Tx$ over $z$ wth $\|z\|_q \le 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any nonzero $x$ and let $y=x/\|x\|_p$. Take any  $z\in \ell^q$ and put $w=z/\|z\|_q$. Then $\|y\|_p=\|w\|_q=1$. Applying $$\tag{1}||x||_p = \max_{||z||_q \leq 1} z^T x$$ to $y$ and $w$, we get
$$
|w^Ty|\leq\|y\|_p=1.
$$
That is,
$$
\frac{|z^Tx|}{\|x\|_p\,\|z\|_q}\leq1,
$$
which is Hölder.

Regarding the "low level" proof, as far as I can tell to show $(1)$ you need Hölder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not understanding why does $\|y\|_p=\|w\|_q=1$ hold here? What if we don't know the original definition of p-norm, what if p-norm and q-norm are just dual and no other assumption is imposed.

Comment: Positive scalars can be taken in an out of a norm. $$\left\|\frac x{\|x\|_p}\right\|_p=\frac{\|x\|_p}{\|x\|_p}=1.$$ I am not using any (concrete) definition of norm, just that they are norms and that your equality is satisfied.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is enlightening.